# run python script multiple times with different files from differents directories

Tags: python, csv, directory, path, exec

I tried to execute a python script multiple times but with different CSV Files from different directories but I know how to do it with just one directory...

Here is the tree structure:

```
Directory_1
 |
 |---> FileA
 |---> FileB
 .....

Directory_2
 |
 |---> File2_A
 |---> File2_B
 .....
```

My code:

```
import os
import sys

directory1_path = "CSV_Files/FileX_CSV/"
directory2_path = "CSV_Files/File2_X_CSV/"


for fileX in os.listdir(directory1_path):
    if fileX.endswith(".csv"):
        with open(os.path.join(directory1_path , fileX)):
            os.system(f'python LoadingX.py -i1 {fileX}  -i2 {file2_x} -o1 LoadX_concat.csv )
```

I have to read and run the python command line with the same file names, for example :

```
first run: -i1 file_A -i2 file2_A
second execution: -i1 file_B -i2 file2_B
...etc
```

But I don't see how I can manage this problem with the current for loop that checks if the CSV file exists and gets its name... On the other hand, I know that for the line with the open, I can handle it several times at the same time.

Comment: How do you know which files from `Directory_1` and `Directory_2` should match together in the same call? Are they both sorted and match by name?

Comment: The folders don't have the same name at all, but the files inside are sorted alphabetically. So the file A of the first folder is processed with the file A of the second. Then the file B of the first folder with the file B of the second...etc

Comment: What about `multiprocessing`?

Answer (score 0):

Provided the files will be sorted in both directories and match pair by pair based on order, you can just [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) them together, iterating on both directories at once. You can also [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) only the CSV's for iteration.

```
import os

directory1_path = "CSV_Files/FileX_CSV/"
directory2_path = "CSV_Files/File2_X_CSV/"

is_csv = lambda f: f.endswith(".csv")
dir1csvs = filter(is_csv, os.listdir(directory1_path))
dir2csvs = filter(is_csv, os.listdir(directory2_path))
for f1, f2 in zip(dir1csvs, dir2csvs):
    os.system(f'python LoadingX.py -i1 {f1}  -i2 {f2} ...')
```

Based on your question, I don't see a reason for you to [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) the files, because you seem to be only using their names as parameters.

Comment: Also, consider using [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) for filtering the filenames in the directories.